# Unreal Engine Character Replication. Where to find out what exactly is being replicated? Is the Material replicated?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

I have been experimenting with Steamworks SDK and Unreal Engine. I have managed to successfully code the connectivity part (ie. I can connect to a Steam Lobby with several players and it will then travel us into the game map with one client then being the host server.).

Everything went swimmingly to begin with (all the player locations/rotations are being replicated), but if I set the material of the player on the server it didn't seem to replicate down to the clients.

I spent a long while reading the documentation and also trying to read through the Engine code, but sadly I cannot confirm or deny if the material is supposed to be replicated as part of the default replication in the UE4 Character class.

Should I be able to set the material only on the server, or should I instead do it on ALL clients, for EACH player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, material and material instances are not replicated.  You need to make sure that they are set to be replicated and use a RepNotify to pass the info to the server.

Comment: Thank you . I have managed to replicate my own created variables but still struggling doing the Material since it was already there on the Character and I don't know how to set that variable up for replication. However I ended up moving onto another part of the coding of the game and so I think I will have to come back to the material later on. Thank you for the help though this will help me get started on the problem when I come back to it.